# I am trying to fetch post data from post table in React Native

Tags: react-native

Screenshot:

[image]

Error:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, text, slug, user}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the posts response is an Object, you should correctly format the object to show you in the code 
Example

```
<Text>{posts._id}</Text>
<Text>{posts.slug}</Text>
<Text>{posts.text}</Text>
```

you could also make this to see what is inside

```
{JSON.stringify(posts)}
```